# My output keeps repeating itself.What do I do?

Tags: python, for-loop, repeat

I was asked to do a python code on calculating an employee's daily wages using for loop. I don't know why but the output keeps repeating itself.
This is the code-

```
Name=input("What is the employee's name?")
days = input("Enter Days:")
h = float(days)
for i in range(1,31):
   if h<= 19:
    wage=(h*50)
    print(wage)

   elif 20 <= h <= 24:
    wage=(h*100)
    print(wage)

   elif 25 <= h <= 27:
    wage=(h*125)
    print(wage)
    

   elif 28 <= h <= 31:
    wage=(h*150)
   print(wage)
```

This is the output:

```
What is the employee's name?James

Enter Days:23
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
2300.0
```

Comment: `h` is invariant in the loop, and since `wage` is computed solely based on `h` it is invariant as well. What did you intend to get for output?

Comment: Could you please tell us what the for loop is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Bet this has to do something with the lone `i` in the `for` loop.

You may have more success changing the code to:

Example:

```
for h in range(1,31)
```

Comment: The variable h is from the user input. If you use it for the loop, you ignore the user input.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the for loop

```
Name=input("What is the employee's name?")
days = input("Enter Days:")
h = float(days)

   if h<= 19:
    wage=(h*50)
    print(wage)

   elif 20 <= h <= 24:
    wage=(h*100)
    print(wage)

   elif 25 <= h <= 27:
    wage=(h*125)
    print(wage)
    

   elif 28 <= h <= 31:
    wage=(h*150)
   print(wage)
```

Comment: Yeah,I know that but the question specifies that we have to use the for loop.Would you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the point of the loop is to *add* to your wages as `i` increases. Something like

```
wages = 0
for i in range(1, h+1):
    if i <= 19: 
        wages += 50
    elif i <= 24:
        wages += 100
    elif i <= 27:
        wages += 125
    else:
        wages += 150
```

But you don't need to iterate over the number of days; the number of marginal rates is small enough that you can just do something like

```
wages = 0
if h > 27:
    wages += (h - 27) * 150
    h = 27
if h > 24:
    wages += (h - 24) * 125
    h= 24
if h > 19:
    wages += (h - 19) * 100
    h = 19
wages += h * 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program first takes a variable days as its input, converts the input into a float and then loops in the range(1,31)

```
days = input("Enter Days:")
h = float(days)
for i in range(1,31):
```

as the expression 20 <= h <= 24 evaluates to true for the given input

```
elif 20 <= h <= 24:
    wage=(h*100)
    print(wage)
```

the program now loops through the expression 31 times evaluation it every time, printing out the output wage in return

```
days = input("Enter Days:")
h = float(days)
for i in range(1,31):
    if 20 <= h <= 24:
        wage=(h*100)
        print(wage)
```

if you want the program to print out the variable wage only once, just remove the for loop

```
Name=input("What is the employee's name?")
days = input("Enter Days:")
h = float(days)

if h<= 19:
    wage=(h*50)
    print(wage)

elif 20 <= h <= 24:
    wage=(h*100)
    print(wage)

elif 25 <= h <= 27:
    wage=(h*125)
    print(wage)
    

elif 28 <= h <= 31:
    wage=(h*150)
    print(wage)
```

Comment: Yeah,I know that but the question specifies that we have to use the for loop.

Comment: If you want to use the for loop anyway, use it with a break cal in every if-else condition so that the loop breaks once a condition is satisfied

Comment: or you can just update the value of i once the condition is satisfied